# Mozilla JetPack Invalid Filename

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I'm trying to create simple Mozilla add-on which is using external JS file;

**Folders & Files**

```
/var/www/html/add-ons/hello
/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/index.js
/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/package.json
/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/script/data/test.js
```

**/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/index.js**

```
// Import the page-mod API
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

// Create a page-mod
pageMod.PageMod({
    include             : "*",
    contentScriptFile   : "./test.js",
    contentScript: 'window.alert("loaded");'
});
```

**/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/package.json**

```
{
  "title": "My Jetpack Addon",
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A basic add-on",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
    "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "jetpack"
  ]
}
```

**/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/script/data/test.js**

`alert("Hello World");`

**Commands I Run to Test**

`cd /var/www/html/add-ons/hello`

`jpm init` (actually package.json file was created by this command)

`jpm run -b /usr/bin/firefox` (I use Ubuntu so I run it this way)

I test it live and I get `loaded` alert however I get following error;

`console.error: script: 
  Error opening input stream (invalid filename?): resource://script/data/test.js`

The folders and file are already exist within the root folder.

If this is the root;
`/var/www/html/add-ons/hello` shouldn't `resource://script/data/test.js` be referring to `/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/script/data/test.js`?

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are u running jpm run from? it has to be from '/var/www/html/add-ons/hello' folder?

Comment: also dump the entire folder structure of your add-on root folder

Comment: @Nandu thanks for the reply. Yes, I do run JPM on ```/var/www/html/add-ons/hello``` Maybe better question would be where this ```resource://``` referring to ?

Comment: your folder structure is wrong. please refer to answer for a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your folder structure as below:
root folder: /var/www/html/add-ons/hello

place index.js, package.json within root folder.
move all the data that is packaged within your add-on to: /var/www/html/add-ons/hello/data

**go to root folder - /var/www/html/add-ons/hello
run jpm run -b**

this will create an xpi package, launch firefox.exe with temporary profile, install add-on.

```
ex: this is from win 7 x64 test project:

root directory: E:\Training\using_Angular

 Directory of E:\Training\using_Angular

11/01/2015  08:26 AM    <DIR>          .
11/01/2015  08:26 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          data
09/29/2015  05:02 PM               548 index.js
08/12/2015  08:26 PM               221 package.json

 Directory of E:\Training\using_Angular\data

09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          .
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          images
08/12/2015  08:26 PM               446 lang.json
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          lib
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          scripts
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          styles
09/29/2015  05:04 PM    <DIR>          html


Directory of E:\Training\using_Angular\data\html
08/12/2015  08:26 PM               446 pagescript.html
```

During run, the 'resource://' folder refers to contents packaged in your add-on.

for ex: resource://caaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/data/html/pagescript.html

Comment: Can you also share the structure of ```package.json``` please? Is the name ```html```?

Since ```/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/script/data/``` didn't work and according to your example I tried to my ```test.js``` in ```/var/www/html/add-ons/hello/data/script/``` it still doesn't work!

Comment: BTW ```jpm run -b /usr/bin/firefox``` maybe executing it this way is the problem? I can't run it via ```jpm run -b``` it gives this error; ```error: option `-b, --binary <path>' argument missing``` It is an Ubuntu related issue.

Comment: please upload your code to github and share a link, i can take a look

Comment: I don't use GitHub, I think I made my question better right now with editing it. I'll check GitHub and get back to you though. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason I checked it out (after restarting my laptop, as I rarely do), it just works now. I'm guessing it has to do with installing the JPM without restart or some other issue but it just works without any changes now. Thank you.